# custom url parameters for api endpoint

Tags: httpie

Using HTTPie https://httpie.org/doc#usagehow do I create a custom URL that I can use to insert my api endpoint?

if given a base url for example that I want to append a date too to reach the endpoint

```
/myURL/data

/myURL/data/yyy/mm/dd
```

how can I add the date programmatically in the url to reach the endpoint repeatedly over days. For today it would look like

```
/myURL/data/2017/07/13
```

Ultimately I will be calling this daily so want to be able to set this up

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you using? It looks like your options are OSX or Linux so this should work on either.

You can use the `date` program to format todays date:

```
date +%Y/%m/%d
```

Which (today) outputs `2017/07/13`.

You could roll a small script to construct your URL parameter and call `httpie`, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%Y/%m/%d)

http /myURL/data/$today
```

Which would execute `http /myURL/data/2017/07/13`

Then you could set up a `cron` (or `launchd` on OSX) to call the script each day.

Comment: Yes i am on linux mint.